# SQL — take Top 3 values from GROUP BY

Tags: sql, group-by, presto

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9F7XPiGtuQAYXQ99HfNJGN/3

```
CREATE TABLE table_1 (
  `country` VARCHAR(2),
  `category` VARCHAR(2),
  `cnt` INT
);

INSERT INTO table_1
  (`country`, `category`, `cnt`)
VALUES
  ('US', 'AA', 20),
  ('US', 'BB', 15),
  ('US', 'CC', 25),
  ('US', 'DD', 30),
  ('FR', 'AA', 10),
  ('FR', 'BB', 5),
  ('FR', 'CC', 50),
  ('FR', 'DD', 60);
```

---

Here's the data:

```
| country | category | cnt |
| ------- | -------- | --- |
| FR      | DD       | 60  |
| FR      | CC       | 50  |
| FR      | AA       | 10  |
| FR      | BB       | 5   |
| US      | DD       | 30  |
| US      | CC       | 25  |
| US      | AA       | 20  |
| US      | BB       | 15  |
```

I want to take the top 3 rows (the top 3 categories) in for each country, ordered by the cnt column. So for example, I'd want:

```
| country | category | cnt |
| ------- | -------- | --- |
| FR      | DD       | 60  |
| FR      | CC       | 50  |
| FR      | AA       | 10  |
| US      | DD       | 30  |
| US      | CC       | 25  |
| US      | AA       | 20  |
```

The table isn't already ordered by cnt. I tried doing LIMIT 3 or TOP 3 but it doesn't do what I want/gives me the top 3 overall, but not for each country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by country order by cnt desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get your result by using `dense_rank()`

```
select 
  *
from 
(
  select 
    *, 
    dense_rank() over (partition by country order by cnt desc) as rn
  from yourTable
) subq
where rn <= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select country, category, cnt from
(select country, category, cnt, row_number() over(partition by country order by cnt 
desc) as rnk from table_1) qry
where rnk between 1 and 3;
```

Demo:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think there is another concept that can be used here, and it is nice to know it.

You can use `max` and `max_by` functions, and use the additional parameter `n` that both functions get, the parameter indicates to return ***n*** values. See [docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.172/functions/aggregate.html#max_by).

So your query would look like:

```
SELECT country, max(cnt,3) top3_cnt, max_by(category,cnt,3) top3_category
FROM table_1
GROUP BY country

-------
Results:
country  top3_cnt       top3_category
FR       [60, 50, 10]   [DD, CC, AA]
US       [30, 25, 20]   [DD, CC, AA]
```

BTW, I like creating the test data using named tables using `WITH`. Instead of really creating tables and inserting data.

So for this query you can use this for test purpose:

```
WITH table_1 (country,category,cnt) AS ( 
 SELECT * FROM (VALUES
  ('US', 'AA', 20),
  ('US', 'BB', 15),
  ('US', 'CC', 25),
  ('US', 'DD', 30),
  ('FR', 'AA', 10),
  ('FR', 'BB', 5),
  ('FR', 'CC', 50),
  ('FR', 'DD', 60) ))
```